How can I see what keys I've added to my keyring in Everquest?
I've been playing a lot in the Tower of Frozen Shadows and I've gotten keys for the first 4 floors. When I right-click on a received key in the tower, the key disappears. I know it gets added to my keyring, but I have no idea where to find it.
Since keys are cross-persona, I'll be back with another class, but can promise that with my memory, I'll have no idea what floors I already have keys for, so that's my question - How can I see what keys I've added to my keyring in Everquest?

According to the official wiki,

To view your keyring, type /keys in your chat window. All of the keys on the ring will then be displayed. To add a key on to the ring, just use it once. Not all keys can be added to the keyring. Once a item key has been added to your keyring, you may destroy the key and it will remain on the keyring, enabling you to have the benefits.

However, this is no longer valid (emphasis mine):

With the release of Terror of Luclin there is no longer a separate "keyring" for keys. Instead the /keys command will open up your Achievements window where a Keys section records your keys.

It still works, essentially, it seems like the command just does a slightly different thing now.
